# Windows Phone entity framework data layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This may seem an odd question, But i've been looking into making a data layer for interfacing with my  windows phone application. I'm maing a windows phone app that records the period of time that a button is pressed, but then i need to send and process this information into an SQL database. The actual application will be relatively small so i won't need  to sue WCF i dont think.

I heard I should use the Web API with ASP.net 4 using an entity framework, but i can't fnd any tutorials. Any suggestions?

Sorry for being annoying i'm just struggling to get anywhere with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First search hit on "web api entity framework": [ASP. NET Web API with Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASP-NET-Web-API-with-afa30545)
.

> This sample contains the completed project for the tutorial Using Web API with Entity Framework on the asp.net/web-api site.Excerpt:This tutorial shows how to use ASP.NET Web API with ADO.NET Entity Framework, using code-first development.Entity Framework is an object/relatio

Comment: I'll see how it goes, fingers crossed i can get something working today

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just connect to remote server using EF ?

Comment: It's not particularly recommended to send plain queries from an application.

Comment: Yeah i was planning on having some sort of service layer with the EF to handle all my data and things.